# Correct Fluent API for one-to-one relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Based on the following models:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Child Child {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

I set up the mapping for classes as follows:

```
public class ParentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("parents");

        this.HasKey(t => t.Id).Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.HasOptional(t => t.Child)
            .WithRequired(t => t.Parent)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}

public class ChildMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("children");

        this.HasKey(t => t.Id).Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.ParentId).HasColumnName("id_parent");
    }
}
```

The navigation properties above are marked `virtual`, however lazy loading is disabled by doing the following:

```
public Abo5Context()
  : base("Name=mydbcontext")
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

A `Parent` can have 0 or 1 `Child` and a `Child` can have 0 or 1 `Parent`.

I'm using eager loading to load the complete entity graph for `Parent`. However, with the above, `Child` is not being loaded. I follow UoW and Repository patterns, and the loading of a `Parent` aggregrate is done as follows:

```
public Parent Get(int id, params Expression<Func<Parent, object>>[] include)
{
    var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<Parent, object>>, IQueryable<Parent>>
              (dbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

    return set.SingleOrDefault<Parent>(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Is this not the correct way for a 1..0-1 relationship configuration?

Comment: You use lazy load, not eager, because you mark your navigation properties as `virtual`

Comment: @SattarImamov They're marked `virtual` but I turned off lazy loading in the dbcontext's initialization.

Comment: @IvanMarkDebono You did not mention about dbcontext configuration. Can you show, how you query your `Parent` model?